# At least one Var equals to X within a Var array using Choco Solver

Tags: constraint-programming, choco

I'm using Choco Solver and given an array of int vars, I want a constraint that check that at least one var in the array is equal to a static value...

Something similar to `IntConstraintFactory#count` but with the following doc :

```
/**
 * Let N be the number of variables of the VARIABLES collection assigned to value VALUE;
 * Enforce condition N >= LIMIT to hold.
 * <p>
 *
 * @param VALUE an int
 * @param VARS  a vector of variables
 * @param LIMIT a variable
 */
public static Constraint at_least(int VALUE, IntVar[] VARS, IntVar LIMIT) {
    return new Constraint("At least", /* help here ? */);
}
```

Does someone knows if it exists or how I can implement it efficiently ?

Comment: One general approach working for most optimization-primitives (SAT, MIP, CP): introduce indicator-constraints, which mark if a variable ```hits``` it's target-value. Then add one of the possible cardinality-approaches available (or just an ```OR``` in your case).

Comment: A common name for this constraint in the CP community is GCC (global cardinality constraint) maybe this will help you finding an answer (I'm not familiar with choco in particular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post constraint `atLeast(VALUE,VARS, LIMIT)` in [Choco Solver](http://choco-solver.org/), you can simply post `count(VALUE,VARS,X)`, with `X` an IntVar of initial domain `[0,VARS.length]`, and post `arithm(X,">=",LIMIT)`. This will do the job. There is no need of implementing a specific constraint for that.

If you want to check that at least one variable in `VARS` is equal to `VALUE`, it is even simpler, simply post `count(VALUE, VARS, X)` with `[1,VARS.length]` as the initial domain for `X`. So the minimal number of occurrence of VALUE will be at least `1`. No need to create a second variable and the arithmetic constraint.